# Prove the equation: $\frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^\infty \frac{\cos kr - ak \sin kr}{k^2a^2 +1} \ldots $

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-analysis

Prove the following equation:

\begin{equation}
\frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^\infty \frac{\cos kr - ak \sin kr}{k^2a^2 +1} \left (\int_0^\infty \cos kr' \left [u(r')-au'(r') \right] dr' \right ) dk =u(r) .
\end{equation}
where $u,u' \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^+)$ and $a,r >0$.

I have found the following not rigorous proof. By reversing the order of integration (this is the not rigorous part) one obtains:
$$
\ldots = \frac{2}{\pi}  \int_0^\infty \left ( \int_0^\infty \frac{\cos kr\cos kr' - ak \sin kr \cos kr'}{k^2a^2 +1} dk \right ) [u(r')-au'(r') ] dr';
$$
By using the Werner formulas, the integral in $dk$ becomes:
\begin{align*}
&  \int_0^\infty \frac{\cos k(r + r') + \cos k(r - r') - ak \sin k(r+r') - ak \sin k(r-r')}{2(k^2a^2 +1)} dk.
\end{align*}
Given the following integrals:
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos kx}{a^2 k^2 +1} dk = \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{e^{-|x/a|}}{a}; \; \; 
\int_0^\infty \frac{ak \sin kx}{a^2 k^2 +1} dk = \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{\text{sgn}(x)e^{-|x/a|}}{a};
$$
the complete formula becomes:
\begin{align*}
&\ldots = \int_0^\infty \Theta(r'-r) \frac{e^{-(r'-r)/a}}{a}[u(r')-au'(r') ] dr' = \\
& - \int_r^\infty \partial_{r'}[ e^{-(r'-r)/a}u(r') ]dr'= - e^{-(r'-r)/a}u(r')  \Big |_{r'=r}^\infty = u(r).
\end{align*}

I think that reversing the order of integration is not allowed, because the conditions for Fubini are not satisfied. In fact, probably:

\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty \left |\frac{\cos kr\cos kr' - ak \sin kr \cos kr'}{k^2a^2 +1} \right | dk = \infty.
\end{equation}

Can somebody give a rigorous proof of the equation?

Comment: If I could prove it with the additional assumption that $r\mapsto ru(r)$ and $r\mapsto ru'(r)\in L^1(\mathbb R^+)$ would it be interesting for you?

Comment: Yes, it would be.